# rmultinom with large integers

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to use the `rmultinom` function in `R` to distribute large populations values and I have had issues with integer overflow.

For example, the following gives me this error:

```
rmultinom(1, 7000000000, prob = c(0.4,0.6))

Error in rmultinom(1, 7000000000, prob = c(0.4, 0.6)) : 
  invalid second argument 'size'
In addition: Warning message:
In rmultinom(1, 7000000000, prob = c(0.4, 0.6)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

I know this is because I am using an integer larger than the `.Machine$integer.max= 2147483647`, but does anyone know a work-around without losing precision in the counts?

Comment: With such large population sizes I would think that any random values are going to end up very, very close to the "true" proportions you give in `prob`. Are you sure that generating these random samples is a useful thing to pursue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you can split it up then it'll work. We can do it in chunks of, say, 1 million measurements

```
chunksize <- 1000000
chunks <- 7000000000 / chunksize

rowSums(rmultinom(chunks, chunksize, prob=c(.4, .6)))
```